# Python: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

My pandas dataframe:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({"A":list("abcde"), "B":list("aabbc"), "C":[1,2,3,4,5]},  index=[10,11,12,13,14])

    A   B   C
10  a   a   1
11  b   a   2
12  c   b   3
13  d   b   4
14  e   c   5
```

My desired output:

```
    A   B   C   a   b   c
10  a   a   1   1   None    None
11  b   a   2   2   None    None
12  c   b   3   None    3   None
13  d   b   4   None    4   None
14  e   c   5   None    None    5
```

Idea is to create new column based on values in 'B' column, copy respective values in 'C' column and paste them in newly created columns. 
Here is my code:

```
lis = sorted(list(dframe.B.unique()))

#creating empty columns
for items in lis:
   dframe[items] = None


 #here copy and pasting
    for items in range(0, len(dframe)):
        slot = dframe.B.iloc[items]
        dframe[slot][items] = dframe.C.iloc[items]
```

I ended up with this error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  app.launch_new_instance()
```

This code worked well in Python 2.7 but not in 3.x. Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with

```
to_be_appended = pd.get_dummies(dframe.B).replace(0, np.nan).mul(dframe.C, axis=0)
```

Then concat

```
dframe = pd.concat([dframe, to_be_appended], axis=1)
```

Looks like:

```
print dframe

    A  B  C    a    b    c
10  a  a  1  1.0  NaN  NaN
11  b  a  2  2.0  NaN  NaN
12  c  b  3  NaN  3.0  NaN
13  d  b  4  NaN  4.0  NaN
14  e  c  5  NaN  NaN  5.0
```

---

Notes for searching.

This is combining one hot encoding with a broadcast multiplication.

Comment: Very easy! Any idea to get None rather than 0?

Answer (score 0):

[Chained assignment will now by default warn if the user is assigning to a copy.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/whatsnew.html)

This can be changed with the option mode.chained_assignment, allowed options are raise/warn/None. See the docs.

In [5]: dfc = DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})

In [6]: pd.set_option('chained_assignment','warn')

The following warning / exception will show if this is attempted.

In [7]: dfc.loc[0]['A'] = 1111

Traceback (most recent call last)
   ...
SettingWithCopyWarning:
   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
   Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead
Here is the correct method of assignment.

In [8]: dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 11

In [9]: dfc

```
 A  B
```

0    11  1

1   bbb  2

2   ccc  3